# Which architecture of Neural Network gives better accuracy for text classification?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have tried and searched, found that RNNs give better results. Which to use: LSTMs or GRU or traditional RNN or CNN?

Answer (score 0):

The architectures you mention are really loose *families* of architecture. Performance depends on the details and (of course) the task. Moreover, the two styles are often combined in various ways, so it isn't really an "either-or" choice.

Nevertheless, at the time of writing the CNN-like [BERT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805) and RNN-like [ELMo](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.05365) architectures are popular. Pre-trained models and code are available for both and they both perform well across a variety of tasks, including classification. Why not try them both?

Answer (score 0):

these architectures can be considered as "vanilla", because there are many advanced architectures that depend on these one, a new one called [ULMFiT](http://nlp.fast.ai/classification/2018/05/15/introducting-ulmfit.html) is . actually giving some state of the art result in classification and is simple to understand and implement using fast.ai library.  BERT is also a good one but more complicated to understand in my opinion.